# Index out of range for delete in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, exception

The following is the code to delete a row from Grid View and update the Content list thereby. But it gives `Index out of range` exception.

```
protected void GridViewD_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            GridViewRow row = GridViewD.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            string itemId;
            //itemId = ((TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;
             itemId = GridViewD.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

            DeleteRow(itemId);
            Bind_Data();
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }

    private void DeleteRow(string itemId)
    {


        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Advertisement");
                SPListItem item = null;
                item = list.GetItemById(int.Parse(itemId));
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                item.Delete();
                list.Update();
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }
        }




    }
```

How to resolve it ?

Comment: Where is the error? Which line? Please provide additional feedback so that others can understand the precise problem.

Comment: While initializing itemid. It is giving error that index is out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error exception is thrown mostly when you try accessing an item at an index that isn't present. The best way to resolve the issue is to debug and check the length of the array or the data table indexes and then see whether you are deleting the correct index or not.

As per described in the comments below you would need to mention the column index that you would want to delete with the `itemId = GridViewD.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value[0].ToString();` statement.

Comment: I have debug it. but how to figure that where is the correct index ?

Comment: I feel that the item index that you are passing is creating a problem. First of all check the whether the index of the row that you want to delete exists in the the data table and does it match the index of the row that you are trying to delete.

Comment: e.RowIndex is correct but it is throughing exeption at  itemId = GridViewD.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to say. I am unable to get it.

Comment: GridViewRow row = GridViewD.Rows[e.RowIndex];  In this e.RowIndex is 4 But at  itemId = GridViewD.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); it is showing negative index.

Comment: You will need to mention the column index with the statement as shown. itemId = GridViewD.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value[0].ToString();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31735/discussion-between-mancy-desaee-and-shahroz-shaikh).

Comment: ok come on chat